# Is there a verbose mode that can be enabled for even more verbose error stacks?

Tags: node.js, typescript, pm2

I have a production only error appearing in my `pm2` logs that is giving me absolutely no helpful information - the callstack is not deep enough to view where it started in my own codebase, and I know of no environment variables that can be modified for more verbose stack tracing

does anyone know of any settings that can effect the callstack

```
App [backgroundExcelIntegration:1] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]
App [backgroundExcelIntegration:1] starting in -fork mode-
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type number (18583)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1522:5)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God/ForkMode.js:258:12
    at wrapper (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16)
    at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/waterfall.js:96:20)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:16
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Utility.js:186:13)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at WriteStream.emit (domain.js:537:15)
    at internal/fs/streams.js:340:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:180:23)
App [backgroundExcelIntegration:1] online
pid=18547 msg=process killed
Deleting process 1
Stopping app:backgroundExcelIntegration id:1
App [backgroundExcelIntegration:1] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
pid=18583 msg=process killed
Exited peacefully
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70317789/the-data-argument-must-be-of-type-string-or-an-instance-of-buffer-typedarray

Comment: If you have this error only in production, chek node, pm2 and other dependencies installed version. It' certainly a compatiblity problem.

Answer (score 2):

the answer ended up having nothing to do with node or typescript, it was a PM2 error, after observing `pm2 monit` it was discovered the server was crashing every 88 seconds (why 88 i have no idea), seemingly others have experienced similar issue and resolved it by running `pm2 update`

we ran `pm2 update` and the issue resolved itself