# Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency (cPanel Phusion Passenger)

Tags: node.js, npm

i am currently facing this issue with my app running on cPanel with Phusion Passenger (hosted on o2switch).

I'm not getting this issue on startup but if i dont do any request on the website for about 10 minutes and then do a new request the app will restart giving me this warning :

```
(node:4909) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I checked first that i dont have any circular depency issue in my code (even if i was kinda sure i didnt) with this commande :

```
madge --circular myApp
```

I am on node 16.13.0 and i have packages that requires node16.
My packages are :

```
"dependencies": {
 "discord.js": "^13.2.0",
 "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
 "ejs": "^3.1.6",
 "express": "^4.17.1",
 "google-spreadsheet": "^3.1.15",
 "googleapis": "^92.0.0",
 "moment": "^2.29.1",
 "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
 "riotgames-gg": "^0.0.7"
}
```

With a catch on the warnings i get these informations :

```
About to exit with code: 0
Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
 at emitCircularRequireWarning (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:707:11)
 at Object.get (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:721:5)
 at Object.exports.setLevels (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/node/vendor-copy/winston/lib/winston/common.js:35:14)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/node/vendor-copy/winston/lib/winston.js:84:8)
 at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
 at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
 at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
 at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
 at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english (i am french)

Comment: I'm not an expert but a while ago watched [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713565/accessing-non-existent-property-padlevels-of-module-exports-inside-circular-de) that can help you