# Firebase Accessing non-existent property 'db' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase with Node.js, there's multiple modules besides index.js and most of my modules needs to access admin and db. Accessing admin and db like this;

**admin.js**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = { admin, db };
```

**index.js**

```
const { admin, db } = require('./admin');
```

I wasn't getting errors while I was using node 12 but after upgraded to node 16, started to get this error;

> (node:1) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'db' of module exports inside circular dependency
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Throwing this error every time any function requested but my application works well. It's accessing db without any problem

Comment: can you tell which firebase tool version you are using?

Comment: I figured out what's wrong, some of old functions were passing 'db' and 'fv' like this;

exports.userProfile = function(data, context, db, fv)

and I changed this module's usage to same as index.js and called them at top of the module.

Circular dependency issue is passing required parameter to another module from called module instead of main one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Arif :

> This issue was because of  some of old functions were passing 'db' and
> 'fv' like this; exports.userProfile = function(data, context, db, fv)
> and he changed this module's usage to same as index.js and called them
> at top of the module. Circular dependency issue is passing required
> parameters to another module from the called module instead of the
> main one.

As mentioned in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65212893/15774176) this issue sometimes could be because Newer NodeJS versions no longer allow circular dependencies.

> **Eg** - There are two files - FileA.js, FileB.js
>
> **Where FileA.js has**
>
> const FileB = require("FileB");
>
> **and FileB.js has**
>
> const FileA = require("FileA");
>
> After removing one of these circular
> dependencies by modifying either FileA.js or FileB.js.

If issue still persist try using command : npm update